# GET http://localhost:8080/app/rest/students?cacheBuster=1419227738006 404 (Not Found)

Tags: rest, caching, resources

When I make a ReST call to my Rest resource I keep getting this

```
GET http://localhost:8080/app/rest/students?cacheBuster=1419227738006 404 (Not Found)
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means that resource couldn't be found.

Comment: what does the cacchebuster mean??

Comment: @user3799365: It's just a GET parameter that causes browsers not to cache the resource. `/students?foo=asfdgfd` has the same effect if the value in unique.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP error code means that the URL you have requested does not exist on the server (localhost in your case).  That could be because either:

- The URL is invalid, i.e. you mis-typed it.  OR
- The server is down at the moment (not necssarily the machine itself, but the process that serves that URL).